# Time complexity bounded by omega

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Hi I was wandering if this statement is true.

if `f(n) = omega(g(n))` and `g(n) = omega(f(n))`

does it mean that `f(n) = theta(g(n))` or `g(n) = theta(f(n))`?

Could anyone clarify this for me?

Comment: Both, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

You can change these symbols for `< >` if you want. It is basically how it works in terms of complexity (not the algebra, therefore you cannot use the `<>` directly)

`f(n) <= g(n)`

`g(n) <= f(n)`

Yes, it means that `g(n) = f(n)` (in complexity, therefore you can read it as `g(n)` has same complexity as `f(n)`)

In formal complexity world, you use Theta for that.